# How to take the value of a JTextField after being modified by the user [java]

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, netbeans-7

I have an empty JTextField that the user should modify with an int number. However, even once the JTextFiled has been filled with an integer, when I go to get the String from that JTextField, the string results "" (-> empty).
How could I save the new value of the Field? what should I do? 
Here's the problem:

```
//Class where JTextField is initialized: 

 javax.swing.JTextField tMax = new javax.swing.JTextField();
 tMax.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                tMaxKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
private void tMaxKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
// TODO add your handling code here:
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(!(Character.isDigit(c) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) {
        getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
}
public String getTMax() {
    String tMaxString = tMax.getText();
    return tMaxString;
}


//Class where tMax should be used

    //code
   private void runBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   Panel class1 = new Panel();
   String tMaxString = class1.getTMax();
   System.out.println(tMaxString);
```

When I run the program and I click the Run Botton an `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`.

What can I do for saving the modified JTextField? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: KeyListener is not what you want.  Use an ActionListener.  Tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Comment: @Pino Any reason that you are not importing the packages like `java.awt`, `javax.swing` ? Your codes are kinda hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I managed this issue by using a DocumentListener. Here's the solution:

```
package AppPackage;


import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

        public class Test {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JTextField option = new JTextField("HI", 10);
            static String optionString;

            public Test() {
               option.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        warn();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        warn();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        warn();
                    }

                    public void warn() {
                        optionString = option.getText();
                        System.out.println(optionString);
                    }
                });
                panel.add(option);
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

              public static void main(String[] args) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                             new Test();
                         }
                    });
              }
      }
```

Hope this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 3):

You have your tMax field defined twice. Once as an instance variable and once as a local variable.

Get rid of the local variable:

```
//javax.swing.JTextField tMax = new javax.swing.JTextField();
tMax = new javax.swing.JTextField();
```

> even once the JTextFiled has been filled with an integer,

Don't use a KeyListener to edit the text as it is typed. Instead you should be using:

1. a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)
2. a [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)
3. a [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Comment: Should I use one of these in the ActionPerformed method of the JTextField?

Comment: This suggestion has nothing to do with the actionPerformed() method. There is no need for an ActionListener. The editing is done as you type. What happened when you tried the suggestion???

Comment: At last I used a DocumentListener and it worked great!